# KendoUI Observable vs kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend : accessing a grid by identity returns null

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, observable

A question I hope someone might be able help me with. The example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/falafelsoftware/9RQy6/

works perfect if I create the viewmodel as in the line below

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable
```

but I have built a project using

```
var viewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend
```

to create the viewmodels as many of the examples in the Telerik Appbuilder do. The problem is using that syntax, the inner functions of the viewmodel are not aware of the identity of the grid - its object value is returned null.

i.e. a method within the viewmodel that invokes :

```
var grid = $("#mygrid").data("kendoGrid") returns null
```

If possible can someone point out why this is so?

```
viewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject.extend({
app.candwService = {    

// other functions ...
//your csv export function:
exportCsv: function (gridId, fileName) {

....

var grid = $("#mygrid").data("kendoGrid"); //=null
//ABOVE GRID IS NULL
}

viewModel: new myViewModel()    
};
})(window);
```

Interestingly this works ok :

window.$("#WineEventsGrid").data("kendoGrid")

so have gone ahead and used that in the code for now, but if there is something I should be doing different/or I am doing incorrrect would love to know.

Thank you for any pushes in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think I pretty much have the answer, is just scoped to the window object. All is working well.